# Can be Nanoframework be used with VB.NET?

Tags: nanoframework

I just discover this framework. I usually code in VB.NET not C#.
I'd like to known if there is a way to use nano framework with VB.NET, and also if it's possible to use Jetbrains Rider instead of VisualStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET nanoFramework only supports C#, not VB.NET.
It could though. For this to happen it would require a fair amount or work in order to provide the BCL and the respective support on the execution engine.
FYI, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/424) where this has been discussed. Despite a few attempts and some potential interest showned, it ended up without any real commitment from the community to make it happen.

Comment: So there isn't  any other way to use VB.NET on embedded device?